# How to keep looping within a python dictionary to search for values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
parent = {'Amy':'Ben', 'May':'Tom', 'Tom':'Ben',
 'Ben':'Howard', 'Howard':'George', 'Frank':'Amy',
 'Joe':'Bill', 'Bill':'Mary', 'Mary':'Philip', 'Simon':'Bill',
 'Zoe':'Mary'}
```

This is the parent dictionary mentioned in the question. My task is to:

find out whether the 2 names inputted are ancestors. For example, Amy's parent is Ben, Ben's parent is Howard, so Howard and Amy are related as ancestors.

Below is my code:

```
    def is_ancestor(name1,name2,pdict):
        for name in pdict:
            parent = pdict.get(name2)
            parent2 = pdict.get(parent)
            if(name1 == parent2):
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

This will work for the example case i mentioned above. But what if the question is 'Amy' and 'Howard'? It should return True as 'Amy' parent is 'Tom', Tom parent is Ben and Ben parent is Howard. So amy and howard are ancestors. But my code will stop after getting tom and ben. how to keep it looping till i meet with a correct answer?

Below is the exact Question:

> Person A   is  an  (indirect)  ancestor    of  Person  B   if  Person  B   is  considered  to  be  one of  the many    descendants of  Person  A.
>
> In the example ancestry    tree    given   above,  Howard  is  an  ancestor    of  Amy,    but Amy is  not an  ancestor    of  Tom.
>
> And    that    person himself  is  NOT his own ancestor. Your  task    is  to  write   a   function,
>   `is_ancestor(name1,name2,pdict)`, that takes   in  three   arguments.
>
> The    first   two arguments   are the names   of  people  (strings),  while   the third   argument    is
>   the    parent  dictionary  mentioned   above.
>
> The    function    should  return  the boolean value   ‘True’  if  the first   person  in  the 
>   argument   list    is  an  ancestor    of  the second  person,
>
> and    ‘False’ if  the first   person  in  the argument    list    is  not an
>   ancestor   of  the second  person.

Comment: What you might be looking for is [Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion instead of a loop.

```
def is_ancestor(name1, name2, pdict):
    parent = pdict.get(name2, None)
    if not parent:
        return False
    elif parent == name1:
        return True
    else:
        return is_ancestor(name1, parent, pdict)

parents = {'Amy':'Ben', 'May':'Tom', 'Tom':'Ben',
 'Ben':'Howard', 'Howard':'George', 'Frank':'Amy',
 'Joe':'Bill', 'Bill':'Mary', 'Mary':'Philip', 'Simon':'Bill',
 'Zoe':'Mary'}

print(is_ancestor("Amy", "Ben", parents))
print(is_ancestor("Ben", "Amy", parents))
print(is_ancestor("Howard", "Amy", parents))
```

The function gets the parent of `name2`. If no parent is found, we've reached the base case and we return `False`. Otherwise, we check to see if the parent found is the one we're looking for. If it is we return `True`. If not, we look to see if *that* person's parent is the ancestor we're looking for. This will keep recursing until we either reach the ancestor we're looking for, or we hit a person with no parent in the dictionary.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, recursion totally skipped my mind. Thanks again

Comment: It's wrong - try e.g ```is_ancestor("Joe", "Philip", parents)```

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski It returns `False` as it should. Joe is not an ancestor of Philip. Philip is an ancestor of Joe.

Answer (score 3):

Here is your answer using recursion:

```
def is_ancestor(name1, name2, pdict):

    try:
        if pdict[name1] == name2:
            return True
        else:
            return is_ancestor(pdict[name1], name2, pdict)
    except KeyError:
        return False
```

First it checks if it has found a direct ancestor, if not, checks the next generation by recursing over the same function. The KeyError exception gets triggered if the ancestor is not found, indicating that `name2` is not an ancestor of `name1`.

Comment: Yes, i totally forgot about recursion. Thanks for your help

Comment: No problem. Glad to help out :D

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
parent = {
    'Amy':'Ben', 
    'May':'Tom', 
    'Tom':'Ben', 
    'Ben':'Howard', 
    'Howard':'George', 
    'Frank':'Amy', 
    'Joe':'Bill', 
    'Bill':'Mary', 
    'Mary':'Philip', 
    'Simon':'Bill', 
    'Zoe':'Mary',
}


def is_ancestor(name1, name2, pdict):
    while name1 in pdict:
        name1 = pdict[name1]

        if name1 == name2:
            return True

    return False


assert is_ancestor('Amy', 'Amy',parent) == False
assert is_ancestor('Amy', 'Ben',parent) == True
assert is_ancestor('Ben', 'Amy',parent) == False
assert is_ancestor('Amy', 'Howard',parent) == True
assert is_ancestor('Howard', 'Amy', parent) == False
assert is_ancestor('Amy', 'George', parent) == True
assert is_ancestor('George', 'Amy', parent) == False
```

Answer (score 1):

### What you got wrong

What happens in your code, is that you're only checking the parent, and not any further. You need to keep traversing the chain up, until you find an ancestor, or run out of names

### The solution

Here is a simple approach to the problem:

```
def is_ancestor(name1,name2,pdict):
    child = name1
    while True:
        if child not in pdict:
            return False
        if pdict[child] == name2:
            return True
        child = pdict[child]
```

### Explanation

Here you check if the child you're checking has a parent. If not, return `False` if it does, than check if that parent is the person you're looking for. If it's not, set that child as the parent, and repeat the process.