# Is there a way to continue after return?

Tags: python

Is there any way to do change the if statement to an one liner?

`

```
def A(N1,N2,dict):
    p = N2
    if N1 == N2:
        return False
    while N1 != p:
        p = dict.get(p,False)
        if p == False:
            return False
    return True
```

`

To something like

`

```
def A(N1,N2,dict):
    p = N2
    return False if N1==N2 else continue
    while N1 != p:
        p = dict.get(p,False)
        return False else continue
    return True
```

`

Comment: why? do you have some scarcity of lines? What exactly doesn't work for you with the code you posted?

Comment: in the first one, did you mean `p == False`?

Comment: Try reading about generators in python and the `yield` keyword.

Comment: I am just trying to reduce the number of lines in it to make it more efficient

Comment: @Lolfoollor how does reducing the line count improve efficiency? Your code seems fine.

Comment: I think you're doing the same homework as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58285723/how-to-keep-looping-within-a-python-dictionary-to-search-for-values/58285895)

Comment: Well it is the same homework I think just that I would like to know if I can use return False if condition else continue

Comment: Should that be `while N1 != p`? As is, `N1 != N2` will *always* be true if it is ever true, and the only way you'll return is by `dict.get` eventually returning `False`. In that case, the iteration is pointless; the function will *always* return `False` eventually.

Comment: @chepner Sorry I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

if you need a oneliner why you don't just write it in one line?

```
if N2==N1: return False
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a one line solution, here it is. Don't get me wrong, this is *NOT* good Python. You should write code which is easy to understand. But it works.

```
A = lambda N1,N2,dict: False if not dict.get(N2, None) else (True if dict.get(N2, None) == N1 else A(N1, dict.get(N2, None), dict))
```

Also, credit where credit is due, this is esentially a refactor of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58286037/4441404) from the other question about the same homework.

Optimised it slightly further:

```
A = lambda N1,N2,dict: (not (not dict.get(N2, None) ) ) and ( dict.get(N2, None) == N1 or A(N1, dict.get(N2, None), dict) )
```

Comment: Thanks but I just want the 1 liner for the If. However, I think I will just go back using the original one I guess since it doesn't work.